# Can't install Windows 7 on my laptop due to drivers not being found

Tags: windows-7, drivers, windows-installation

I have a laptop Dell Inspiron-14R and, previously, had Fedora installed.

Now I am trying to install Windows 7 and it shows a message saying

> Driver not found

Comment: Where exactly does it give that error message? BIOS? POST? BOOT? Setup?

Comment: x64 or x86 bit system you are trying to install?

Comment: What is the "it" that shows the message?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz +1 for the existential question! :) http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58329/it-is-an-existential-question

Comment: @Kris I was trying to be serious. Something showed that message, he doesn't say what, and it matters.

Comment: I know, even I was. But the way you put it made me +1 you.

Comment: Checking on Dell's site, they only provide drivers for 64-bit Windows 7

Comment: More than likely the message is "Drive Not Found", they need a Sata driver loaded at the start of setup.

Answer (score -1):

When you install windows 7, you might be using one of many possible install disks. From the limited details, one would assume that you are not using the Dell Windows 7 install DVD, but perhaps the generic Windows 7 install disk (ie store bought). The difference is that the Vendor specific version includes all the drivers that the vendor supports for that OS. 
You can still continue with the non-Vendor install disk, if you visit the Dell support site and download the latest Windows 7 drivers for that model (use your service tag sticker number). You can be selective and only download the drivers that appear with questions marks when you view the windows 7 device manager.

Answer (score -1):

```
Insert the DVD into the DVD drive.
On the disk selection screen, press SHIFT+F10. A Command Prompt window opens.
Type diskpart, and then press ENTER to open the diskpart tool.
Type list disk, and then press ENTER. A list of available hard disks is displayed.
Type sel disk number, and then press ENTER. number is the number of the hard disk that you want to clean. The hard disk is now selected.
Type det disk, and then press ENTER. A list of partitions on the hard disk is displayed. Use this information to verify that the correct disk is selected.
Make sure that the disk does not contain required data, type clean all, and then press ENTER to clean the disk. All the partitions and all the data on the disk is permanently removed.
Type exit, and then press ENTER to close the diskpart tool.
Close the Command Prompt window.
Click the Refresh button to update the disk selection screen. This step lists the disk.
Run Windows Setup to perform a clean installation of Windows.
```

Comment: Please provide your source for this information.

Answer (score -4):

To the extent I have seen, `Driver not found` is quite a generic error message.

You will probably need to coax the installation process to come up with more, specific clues.

Comment: Not only do you not answer the question, which granted, is very vague, but you also give an equally vague suggestion to narrow down he problem

Comment: -1 "coax" now that's a new computer term.